# EC2 - how much more diskspace I get when upgrade from T2.Medium to T2.Large

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ubuntu-16.04, amazon-ebs

I have upgraded my instance from EC2 T2.Medium to T2.Large.  However, I do not see any change in the available disk space.  How do I get more space?  I am using Ubuntu 16.04.  Do I need to execute any Linux shell commands?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Amazon Elastic Block Store (EBS) is network-attached disk storage that is (normally) used as Boot Disks and Storage Disks. The size of the disk volume is **independent from the Instance Type**. In fact, disks can be detached from one instance and attached to another one, so they are also independent of the EC2 instance itself.

There is another storage type called [Amazon EC2 Instance Store](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/InstanceStorage.html) that is **directly attached to the host computer** and *does* vary by Instance Type. However, the T2 family of EC2 instances does not have Instance Store.

**Bottom line:** If you want to resize a disk, do it directly to the EBS disk itself.

See: [Modifying the Size, IOPS, or Type of an EBS Volume on Linux - Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ebs-modify-volume.html)